Why does verification of ecdsa signature fail - python?
I try to build and verify a ecdsa signature...and... I fail.
I want do built a signature, that validates against a given validation method (like the one "def validate(signature, payload, certID):")
I believe I use a private key and the corresponding public one.
I believe I use the same payload / message.
import hashlib
import os
import ecdsa

keyidentifyer = "T01UTS004015"
payload = "lorem ipsum".encode()

def validate(signature, payload, certID):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Dokumente', 'publiccerts', certID + '.pem')
    key_file = open(path, "rb")
    key = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_pem(key_file.read())
    print("payload used for verify sig: ")
    print(payload)
    isvalid = key.verify(signature, payload, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256)
    print(isvalid)
    return isvalid

def sign(payload, certid):
    print("payload used to build sig")
    print(payload)
    path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Dokumente', 'privKeys', certid + '.pem')
    key_file = open(path, "rb")
    key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_pem(key_file.read())
    payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(payload).digest()
    signature = key.sign(payload_hash)
    #for testing - validate signature immediately
    print(validate(signature, payload, certid))

    return signature


sign(payload, keyidentifyer)


This code, on the other hand, works:

def singmessage(payload, sigID):
    signature = ""
    message_hash = hashlib.sha256(payload.encode()).digest()
    path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Dokumente', 'privKeys', sigID+'.pem')
    key_file = open(path, "rb")
    key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_pem(key_file.read())
    signature = key.sign(message_hash)
    return signature
def validatemessage(sig_bytes, payload, sigID):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Dokumente', 'publiccerts', sigID + '.pem')
    key_file = open(path, "rb")
    key = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_pem(key_file.read())
    message_hash = hashlib.sha256(payload.encode()).digest()
    isvalid = key.verify(sig_bytes, message_hash)
    return isvalid


but... when I try to verify a signature that was built with def singmessage(payload, sigID): from the second code, it fails when I am using the function def validate(signature, payload, certID): from the first code.
But it should work?

WHAT fails, exactly?

The ecdsa library hashes implicitly. By default, SHA-1 is used, but this can be changed with the hashfunc= argument in key.sign() and key.verify(), s. the ecdsa docs, sec. Usage.

Therefore, validate() hashes with SHA-256 (implicit), while all other functions hash twice, once with SHA-256 (explicit) and a second time with SHA-1 (implicit), which is why they are incompatible with validate(). For a signing counterpart to validate(), simply remove the explicit hashing and set the implicit hashing to SHA256.

@tim: oh sorry.. of course - bad singature error
File "/home/...path.....venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ecdsa/keys.py", line 741, in verify_digest
raise BadSignatureError("Signature verification failed")
ecdsa.keys.BadSignatureError: Signature verification failed

@Topaco: thx. The error still exists when I alter
signature = key.sign(payload_hash)
to
signature = key.sign(payload_hash, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256)

@Topaco <3
thank you very much! your second comments saved me!

thanks to the hint of @topaco
this code works (I hope it will help someone else):
import hashlib
import os
import ecdsa

keyidentifyer = "T01UTS004015"
payload = "lorem ipsum".encode()

def validate(signature, payload, certID):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Dokumente', 'publiccerts', certID + '.pem')
    key_file = open(path, "rb")
    key = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_pem(key_file.read())
    print("payload used for verify sig: ")
    print(payload)
    isvalid = key.verify(signature, payload, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256)
    print(isvalid)
    return isvalid

def sign(payload, certid):
    print("payload used to build sig")
    print(payload)
    path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Dokumente', 'privKeys', certid + '.pem')
    key_file = open(path, "rb")
    key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_pem(key_file.read())
    #payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(payload).digest()
    signature = key.sign(payload, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256)
    #for testing - validate signature immediately
    print(validate(signature, payload, certid))

    return signature


sign(payload, keyidentifyer)

